# Understanding generic Java class signature in cross compilation with C#

Tags: java, c#, generics, visual-studio-2013, attributes

I have to implement some classes in Java that will pass tests written in C# (using Visual Studio unit tests). I came across problem with this part of test:

```
var portfolioSignatureAttribute = dllType
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(SignatureAttribute), false)
    .Cast<SignatureAttribute>()
    .FirstOrDefault();
Assert.AreEqual("<C::LIConverter<LCurrency;LCurrency;>;>Ljava/util/ArrayList<LBoughtStock;>;Ljava/lang/Iterable<LBoughtStock;>;", portfolioSignatureAttribute.Signature, iterableMessage);
```

The signature I tried writing was, but doesn't work is:

```
public class Portfolio extends ArrayList<BoughtStock> implements IConverter<Currency, Currency>, Iterable<BoughtStock>
```

Also, i got some message thrown by this assertion:

> Type Portfolio incorrect signature. Remember to add generic interface java.lang.Iterable implementation. Remember to give a name C to generic parameter. Remember also to inherit your class from java.util.ArrayList.

And here is also fragment from test output:

```
Result Message: Assert.AreEqual failed. 
Expected:<<C::LIConverter<LCurrency;LCurrency;>;>Ljava/util/ArrayList<LBoughtStock;>;Ljava/lang/Iterable<LBoughtStock;>;>. 
Actual:<Ljava/util/ArrayList<LBoughtStock;>;LIConverter<LCurrency;LCurrency;>;Ljava/lang/Iterable<LBoughtStock;>;>.
```

So generally, there is problem with: lack of "C::" and with order of those attributes. I totally cannot find anywhere any informations about such things, and how to understand it. And the question is - what the class signature should be?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem (by myself, i am proud :) )

The signature should be:

```
public class Portfolio<C extends IConverter<Currency, Currency>> extends ArrayList<BoughtStock> implements Iterable<BoughtStock> {
```